# How do I Transfer the animation from my smart object to my real file

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation

I am using photoshop cs4 currently, but I have photoshop cc at home. I want to know if there was a way to transfer the animation I've worked on the smart object to the original project.

[image: This is the smart Object animation work]

[image: This is the real project I'm working on]

Answer (score 1):

1.) Open the smart object with the animations you want to bring back to the original file.

2.) Navigate to window > arrange > 2 up vertical or 2 up horizontal. This should show both the Original file and the smart object side by side.

3.) Select all the layers in the smart objects layer panel and drag them over to the original files art board and release. This should not only bring the objects you selected, but the animation information with it.